# mac terminal copy command excluding folders

Tags: macos, terminal

In mac catalina, I use this most basic command to copy all files (but not subfolders) of a src directory to dest directory.

> cp ~/dirFrom/* ~/dirTo/

In mac catalina, this command works perfectly, but gives this annoying message that it doesn't copy subfolders (of course because -r argument is left out). This is extremely annoying because I have automator shortcut that pops up this message each time it's run... Question is, how do I get this this annoying message to disappear or to specify not to try to copy folders/directories?

superfluous/unnecessary Message that's popped up every time it runs:

> The action "Run Shell Script" encountered an error: "cp:
>   /dirFrom/subdir is a directory (not copied)

Answer (score 0):

try the -r option, namely cp  -r  ~/dirFrom/*  ~/dirTo/

Answer (score 0):

> rsync -a -f"- /" -f"+ *" ~/src/ ~/dest

copied from https://askubuntu.com/questions/632091/how-can-i-exclude-all-subdirectories-but-include-files-of-a-directory-in-rsync